# How to add a field and value to a post form before sending it in javascript?

Tags: javascript, post, appendchild

My intention against spamming attack on my contact form, use javascript to append a field (is_legit=1) to the form before it is send as POST.

The script works in the fact that the form is send but without the added field.  What I am doing wrong?

This is the js script:

```
<script>
$("#send").click(function() {
    var form = $("contact-form");
    var hiddenVar = document.createElement("input");
    hiddenVar.name="is_legit";
    hiddenVar.id = "is_legit";
    hiddenVar.type="hidden";
    hiddenVar.value = 1;
    $(form).appendChild(hiddenVar);
    $(form).submit();
});
```

and the form with send button:

```
<form id="contact-form" action="/contact" method="post">
<input...>
<button 
    id="send"
    class="button is-link is-primary" 
    name="send">
    send
</button>
</form>
```

Comment: That script can’t really be working, `$("contact-form")` won’t select anything here.

Comment: @CBroe There is no js error and at least the form is sent correctly with $(form).submit();  So can you please help further?

Comment: _“and at least the form is sent correctly with $(form).submit()”_ - no, it is not. It is send based on that your button is a submit button. _“There is no js error”_ - you probably didn’t _see_ them, because the page reloads (because the form submits, the normal way) - so set your browser console to keep error messages beyond a page change.

Comment: The first error you should be getting here, is `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).appendChild is not a function` – appendChild is a native DOM method, you can not call it on a jQuery object. And if you fixed that by using `$(form)[0].appendChild` instead (`[0]` to get the reference to the first DOM element in that jQuery collection), then you would get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined` – because, as I said, `$("contact-form")` did not select any element to begin with.

Comment: @CBRoe how do set Mac Firefox console to keep error messages beyond a page change?

Comment: @CBroe so what should i do?

Comment: Well fix the errors, of course? Is it not clear to you, _why_ `$("contact-form")` does not select any element here? Because there is no element with the _tag name_ `contact-form` anywhere. What does the ID selector in CSS look like again …?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228896/discussion-between-paul-godard-and-cbroe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution. It works 100% with a **send** button in a form **contact-form** by adding an "invisible" field with value 1 to the POST data... I hope this will stop the hacking by the russian bitcoins!

```
$("#send").click(function() {
    var $input = $('<input>').attr({type:'hidden',id:'is_legit',name:'is_legit',value:'1'}).appendTo('#contact-form');
    $('#contact-form').submit();
});
```